# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error The package Newtonsoft.Json with version 12.0.3 could not be found in

Tags: json.net, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I moved a project from one PC to another and compiling the solution I get the following

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     The package Newtonsoft.Json with version 12.0.3 could not be
> found in C:\Users\Usuario.nuget\packages,
> C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet. Run a NuGet package restore to download
> the package.  BusinessLogic

I have already restored it, deleted it, reinstalled it and it continues to appear, what I see is that the routes that tell me there in the error are not on the pc that I brought the project, in the previous one they are

¿but if this is how I can remove these routes or remove this error?

Comment: Is your project a non-sdk net framework or a net core project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check these two options under **Tools**-->**Options**

[image]

Please enable them first. Then, click  **Clear Nuget Caches** button.

**Also**, please make sure that you have enabled `nuget.org` nuget pakage source `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.

If not, please add it:

[image]

**When** you finish them all, close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**After that**, restart your project and then click **Rebuild** button.

Comment: I did the process and I keep getting this error

Comment: click [clean nuget caches button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and then close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. After that, restart VS to test again.

Comment: Besides, close VS, delete the `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then restart your VS to test again. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

copying and renaming the database works for me and connection string also need to be updated to the new database name.